# How to put a tick label at a custom position in JavaFX chart?

Tags: java, javafx, charts, javafx-2, linechart

I'm trying to locate the x-axis labels at a specific position match some points of the chart, however, I have failed. I am using the setTickLabelFormatter method, but it is necessary that the tickunit be 1 to identify all the x-axis values and thus to change the value indicated by a letter and other values should not appear.

```
public void setXAxisFormatter(Map<Integer, String> labels) 
{
    if (chart.getXAxis().getClass().getSimpleName().equals("NumberAxis")) {
        this.tickLabels = labels;
        NumberAxis xAxis = (NumberAxis) chart.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setForceZeroInRange(false);
        xAxis.setTickLabelFormatter(new StringConverter<Number>() {

            @Override
            public String toString(Number object) {                    
                return tickLabels.get(object.intValue());
            }

            @Override
            public Number fromString(String string) {
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

In the chart you can see that the letter "I" actually appears, but the letter "D" does not appear because the ticks are very close and overlap preventing the letter "D" printed.  I do not know how to get that the others null labels are ignored and only print the letters I'm getting.

**Changing the size of the chart to be very long, works well, but do not I need a chart of 800 x 300, I need 400 x 300.**